# Alternar classe do css em um toggle de nav, usando Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou fazendo um menu com um *toggle* utilizando *Jquery*. O menu está funcionando perfeitamente.

Estou utilizando uma classe do *Font Awesome* para mostrar o ícone no botão para ativar o *toggle*. Quero alterar a classe `fa-chevron-circle-down` para `fa-chevron-circle-up` quando o *toggle* for ativado, e retornar a classe para inicial quando o *toggle* for desativado.

Segue o código

### HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-menu">
    <ul class="nav-list shadow">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button class="nav-toogle shadow"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-3x" alt="Menu Arrow"></i>
    </button>
</nav>
```

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-toogle').click(function(){
        $('.nav-list').slideToggle('slow');    
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar o `.toggleClass()` e passar as duas classes separadas por espaços. Uma vez que o elemento que recebe o evento `click` é o `button` tens de selecionar o elemento `i`. Podes fazer isso com `.find('i')`.

O código ficaria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-toogle').click(function(){
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-circle-down fa-chevron-circle-up');
        $('.nav-list').slideToggle('slow');    
    }); 
});
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/6kv3cf9c/

Comment: Obrigado, Sergio. 
Resolveu meu problema. O menu está funcionando perfeitamente.